# What caused Elliot Stabler to be suspended and quit?

Tags: law-and-order-svu

I never really saw the end of season 12 of [*Law & Order: Special Victims Unit*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0203259/) but I did know that throughout the series  Elliot Stabler would get suspended or investigated by Internal Affairs because of him being someone of a "loose cannon".

At the start of Season 13, Stabler has apparently been suspended again just before Amanda Rollins arrives, at the end of the episode Donald Cragen informs Olivia Benson that Stabler had handed in a letter of resignation, Nick Amaro is then called in to replace Stabler (to which Benson was opposed to at first).

Now since I haven't seen or remember what caused Stabler's suspension this time and it would be quite some time until I see it on TV again (maybe never now) I am wondering what Stabler did this time to get suspended and if it affected his decision to quit.

Comment: Your English seems good enough to assume some basic knowledge about punctuation and capitalization. So is this really just laziness (forgive me if it's not, but it wasn't the first instance either)?

Comment: @ChristianRau sorry, i was told back in high school while writing a report for an assignment that i seem to have the tendency in typing what appears in my mind which unfortunately makes it hard for others to read, it's a problem that's been made apparent on other SE sites and even proof reading only helps out a little as i still just end up reading it in my mind and making perfect sense in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the finale of season 12, Stabler (Played by Christopher Meloni) is placed on administrative leave after a shooting incident in the squad room where he kills a woman that came in and opened fire. (Administrative leave is normal while line of duty shootings are investigated for real life police officers).

During the off season, Meloni and the studio could not agree on contract terms, so he "abruptly resigned" from the force. So it wasn't a script decision per se, it was something dictated by off screen events.